# How to get JSON data from MySQL with correct field type?

Tags: mysql, json, go

I am a beginner to Golang. I've read many threads about getting JSON from a mysql database, but there is a question left unanswered: the values of all fields in the JSON are strings and not their correct types, be it integer or time.

The code I'm using:

```
var emptyOut []byte
rows, err := db.Query(sqlString)
if err != nil {
    return emptyOut, err
}
defer rows.Close()
columns, err := rows.Columns()
if err != nil {
    return emptyOut, err
}
count := len(columns)
tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
values := make([]interface{}, count)
valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
for rows.Next() {
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
    }
    rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
    entry := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i, col := range columns {
        var v interface{}
        val := values[i]
        b, ok := val.([]byte)
        if ok {
            v = string(b)
        } else {
            v = val
        }
        entry[col] = v
    }
    tableData = append(tableData, entry)
}
jsonData, err := json.Marshal(tableData)
if err != nil {
    return emptyOut, err
}
return jsonData, nil
```

The part that turns data into string is surely this one:

```
v = string(b)
```

So the question is: how to turn v into the right type of value of b. This will save a lot of my effort in dealin with wrong field type later on. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unclear. The data is stored on MySQL in JSON column, is it? You get this JSON from MySQL as-is, is it? You parse this JSON on Go side and you cannot to parse into correct datatype, is it? So the most first questions: #1. What is precise MySQL version? execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output. #2. Why you not parse on MySQL side retrieving parsed data converted to needed datatype (which is defined by the value path)? Also show your `sqlString` value used for data retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear on the constraints of your problem.

If you know the database schema before hand, I would create a struct that represents your data. You can then use the database library [gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html) to get the data into a struct slice. You can add [go tags](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-struct-tags-in-go) to the struct and convert the struct slice to json with the fields marshaled into their correct types.
For example (untested):

```golang
type MyDataSchema struct {
    Id         int    `json:"id"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Birth time.Time `json:"birth_date,omitempty"`
}
...
rows:=&DataSchema{}
result := db.Find(&rows)
b, err := json.Marshal(result)
```

If you dont know the schema before hand, then it is a little bit more tricky. In go there is such a thing as a [type switch](https://go.dev/tour/methods/16). You might want to consider that:
If I am following your code correctly, `val := values[i]` val is of type interface. So you could do something like (untested):

```
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case int:
        entry[col]=v
    case string:
        entry[col]=v
    case time.Time: 
        entry[col]=v
//you can add more types
    default:
        entry[col]=val
    }
```

This might not be a complete answer but hopefully it gets you to where you need.